# How to set button background from iphone documents folder

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimage

I have image file which is stored in the iphone documents dir when i gave that image to button background it does not show.

```
NSString*imageThumbnailVideo= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@thumbVideo.png",imageThumbnail];

NSLog(@"imageThumbnailVide is %@",imageThumbnailVideo);

NSString * filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@", NSHomeDirectory(),imageThumbnailVideo];

BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
if (fileExists == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"File is Not exists");
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"File is present");
}

[thumbnailImageView setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageThumbnailVideo] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It also shows File is Present but does not display image.

Here is how i am saving the file

```
   testT=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@thumbVideo",titleTextField.text];

    NSString *newStringVT = [testT stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];


    NSString*imageTitleVT=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",newStringVT];


    NSString *pathVT = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageTitleVT];


    NSData*thumbVideoData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnail);

    NSError * error = nil;
    [thumbVideoData writeToFile:pathVT options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *img_path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YOUR IMAGE NAME.png"];

    NSURL*   uurl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:img_path];
[thumbnailImageView setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:uurl]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: why say to use NSURL it simplle  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:img_path];

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the image from a file by doing something like this:

```
UIImage* anImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:validFilePath];
```

and then you can apply that image to a button like this:

```
[_someButton setImage:anImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```